# Extra space in the first page of the LaTeX generated PDF

Tags: latex

I have a following LaTeX script:

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 12pt, oneside]{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[final]{pdfpages}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{pdflscape}
\geometry{a4paper, margin=1cm}
\begin{document}
\pagestyle{empty}

\begin{landscape}
\includegraphics[width=12cm, height=11cm]{/tmp/image1.png}
\hspace{2em}
\includegraphics[width=12cm, height=11cm]{/tmp/image2.png}
\newline
\includegraphics[width=12cm, height=11cm]{/tmp/image1.png}
\hspace{2em}
\includegraphics[width=12cm, height=11cm]{/tmp/image2.png}
\newline
\includegraphics[width=12cm, height=11cm]{/tmp/image1.png}
\hspace{2em}
\includegraphics[width=12cm, height=11cm]{/tmp/image2.png}
\newline
\end{landscape}

\end{document}
```

The problem is that for the very first page there is a few millimeter **extra space** on the left side (**left-top margins are not equal**) - there is no such an extra margin for the following pages which are all the same.

The issue can be seen here:

[image]

Where is the trick/issue here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this is due to the initial indent and can be removed with `\noindent` inside the landscape env.

```
...
\begin{landscape}
\noindent % HERE
\includegraphics[width=12cm, height=11cm]{aplot.png}
\hspace{2em}
...
```

EDIT : All these graphics count as one paragraph, so if you break this paragraph in 2 with a blank line, you'll need to add a second `\noindent`.

Comment: Thanks! Works like a charm! Much appreciated! ;)